# Proving: $2(n-1)<(n+1)\sqrt{n}$

Tags: inequality

How can I prove the following inequality ($n\in N$)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. $$2(n-1)<(n+1)\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: for $n\ge 4$  we have $\sqrt n \ge 2$  and $n+1>n-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$\sqrt{n}\leq \frac{n+1}{2},$$thus$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\geq \sqrt{n}^2=n>n-1.$$

Comment: Succinct. Elegant.

Comment: Why did I just get a downvote?

Answer (score 5):

For $n\ge 4$ the right hand side is $(n+1)\sqrt n\ge (n+1)\cdot 2>2(n-1)$. Check the remaining cases manually: $4\sqrt 3\stackrel?>4$, $3\sqrt2\stackrel?>2$, $2\sqrt 1\stackrel?>0$, $\sqrt 0\stackrel?>-2$.

Comment: Now how do I prove that inequality you've mentioned?